# GitHub Copilot in the CLI cannot authenticate through my token Windows

Tags: github-copilot

I'm trying to install GitHub Copilot in the CLI.
I downloaded the .msi for windows (`gh_2.40.1_windows_amd64.msi`). I created a Powershell Profile:

```
New-Item -path $PROFILE -type file -force
```

I added (replaced my actual token by mytoken, I kept the quotes):

```
$env:GH_TOKEN = "my_token"
```

When I check if everything works by printing:

```
echo $env:GH_TOKEN
```

It works. I see my token.

But when I try to use GitHub copilot it doesn't work:

```
PS C:\Users\lhott> gh copilot explain
✗ Error: No valid OAuth token detected
To get started with GitHub Copilot in the CLI, please run: gh auth login --web -h github.com to authenticate via web browser.

PS C:\Users\lhott> gh auth login --web -h github.com 
The value of the GH_TOKEN environment variable is being used for authentication. To have GitHub CLI store credentials instead, first clear the value from the environment.
```

I ran powershell in Admin mode.
I'm not an expert at computing so I may miss something? Does someone see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried letting the login process store the credentials? There seems to be some issue in the environment variable context.

You first need to delete the GH_TOKEN env variable: `Remove-Item Env:GH_TOKEN`.

Then re-run the authentication command:
`gh auth login --web -h github.com`

If you still cannot log in, the GH_TOKEN environment variable might be set out of session, so delete it from your profile: `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("GH_TOKEN", $null, "User")`

Comment: I needed to delete the TOKEN to be able to authenticate with HTTPS! Thanks.